# Why are my End values giving me a syntax error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

I'm getting the "unexpected keyword_end" error and I'm not completely sure why. I'm trying to gather a count of how many users are in my organization. This is my class:

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, class_name: "user", foreign_key: "user_id"

  def user_count
    users = User.all
    count = 0
    users.each do |user|
        if (user.organization_id == self.id)
            count++ 
        end
    end
    return count
  end
end
```

I tried using `counter_cache`, but this gives me the total number of users rather than how many users are in this organization specifically.

My goal is call this function later in the app to get the count of how many users are a part of this organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`++` operator does not exist in ruby. Go for `count += 1`

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I feel like a fool. I began with Java, did that for LONG time, and am working now as a Ruby dev.